# how to get only placename also it's address of lan and lat

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

this is my code.
i need address of lan and lat.how do it?
following code is not working.why?
i included.
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&sensor=true"

---

```
 function  maps(latss,lngss)
{

 var lat=latss;

 var lng=lngss;
 var places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService( document.createElement( 'div' ) ),
searchRequest = {


     location: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
      radius: 500


};

places.search( searchRequest, function ( results, status ) {

var html = '';

for ( var index = 0; index < results.length; index++ ) {

    html +=
          '<li '
        + 'data-location-id="' + results[index].id + '" '
        + 'data-address="' + results[index].vicinity + '" '
        + 'data-latitude="' + results[index].geometry.location.lat() + '" '
        + 'data-longitude="' + results[index].geometry.location.lng() + '" '
        + 'data-name="' + results[index].name + '">'
        + '<div>' + results[index].name + '</div>'
        + '<div>' + results[index].vicinity + '</div>'
        + '</li>';

};

document.getElementById( 'results' ).innerHTML = html;

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The script as it is  works, issues may be:

- the search didn't give any result(check the status)
- the target-element(`document.getElementById( 'results' )`) is unknown at the time you try to access it
- latss and lngss are not valid values vor a LatLng

However, your debugger should give you more information.

Note: the page must contain a "powered by google"-logo when you use places-results without a google-map.